# Check which button clicked on page leave prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

So I have this code and I'm trying to find out how to check which button the user clicks on the prompt. I'd like to fire an event if they click stay or fire a different event if they leave. Is this possible?

```
    var submitted = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            if (!submitted) {
                var message = "Are you sure you want to leave?", e = e || window.event;
                if (e) {
                    e.returnValue = message;
                }
                return message;
            }
        }

     $("form").submit(function() {
         submitted = true;
     });
    });
```

Comment: If they click yes, then `onunload` will fire. If they don't then it won't fire.

Comment: No. The onbeforeunload prompt is not scriptable

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no way to find that which button is clicked(in case of onbeforeunload confirm box) according to my knowledge.

But we can achieve the required functionality by following way:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if( $("table tbody.files tr.template-download.fade").length > 0 )
    {
        var message = "XYZ",
        e = e || window.event;
        // For IE and Firefox
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = message;
        }
        // For Safari
        return message;
    }
}
```

And you can write the code for 'yes' button click inside following:

```
    $( window ).unload(function() {     
            //--> Here 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

use Javascript "confirm" for that:

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?"))
{
   //True part
}
else
{
   //False part
}
```

Comment: that confirm doesn't give a page leave prompt (whatever it's called. I know it's not technically a typical prompt).

Comment: Note: if the user clicks "OK" the 'True part' will be entered, if "cancel" the false part will be entered.

Comment: How do I trigger this for page leave? Simply dumping it within the onbeforeunload() doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure onbeforeunload() is been called?

Comment: can you test it yourself within this code? I'm having no luck

Comment: This is not that prompt, the question is about window.onbeforeunload